# Convert pandas dataframe to directed networkx multigraph

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx

I have a dataframe as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'source': ('a','a','a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),'target': ('b','b','c', 'a', 'd', 'a'), 'weight': (1,2,3,4,5,6) })
```

I want to convert it to directed networkx multigraph. I do

```
G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'source', 'target', ['weight'])
```

& get

```
G.edges(data = True)
[('d', 'a', {'weight': 6}),
 ('d', 'c', {'weight': 5}),
 ('c', 'a', {'weight': 3}),
 ('a', 'b', {'weight': 4})]
G.is_directed(), G.is_multigraph()
(False, False)
```

But i want to get

```
[('d', 'a', {'weight': 6}),
 ('c', 'd', {'weight': 5}),
 ('a', 'c', {'weight': 3}),
 ('b', 'a', {'weight': 4}),
('a', 'b', {'weight': 2}),
('a', 'b', {'weight': 4})]
```

I have found no parameter for directed & multigraph in this [manual](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html).
I can save `df` as txt and use `nx.read_edgelist()` but it's not convinient

Comment: what version of networkx do you have? I have version 2.1 and `G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'target', ['weight'])` works correctly

Comment: There is a `create_using` argument which takes different graph types. I haven't tried this personally, but perhaps some luck with that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you want a directed multi-graph, you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'source': ('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
     'target': ('b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'a'),
     'weight': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)})


M = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'target', ['weight'], create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())
print(M.is_directed(), M.is_multigraph())

print(M.edges(data=True))
```

**Output**

```
True True
[('a', 'c', {'weight': 3}), ('a', 'b', {'weight': 1}), ('a', 'b', {'weight': 2}), ('c', 'd', {'weight': 5}), ('b', 'a', {'weight': 4}), ('d', 'a', {'weight': 6})]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `create_using` parameter :

> [`create_using`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html) (NetworkX graph) – Use the specified graph for result. The default is `Graph()`

```
G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'source', 'target', ['weight'], create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```